# how to resize polygon in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I draw Polygon with this code:

```
Graphics surface;
surface = this.CreateGraphics();
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Olive);
Point[] points = { new Point(50, 50), new Point(250, 50), new Point(50, 250) };
surface.FillPolygon(brush, points);
```

how to resize polygon Similar to the following?

[Pic](http://inspic.com/7AC68788)

Comment: You need to change the values in your points. <sarcasm/>

Comment: Look into the `System.Drawing.Matrix` class, and the `Graphics.Transform` property.

Comment: @Rotem: please help me for use System.Drawing.Matrix and Graphics.Transform for resize polygon.

Comment: Look into `surface.ScaleTransform()` and `surface.TranslateTransform()` before you draw anything.

Comment: @ja72: I want use center of polygon for resize.

Comment: @Rotem: I studied this article: http://bobpowell.net/transformations.aspx but can not use for resize polygon :-(

Comment: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/01/enlarge-a-polygon-in-c/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var g  = e.Graphics;
var points=new PointF[] { new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(1, 0), new PointF(0, 1) };

var st=g.SaveState();

g.TranslateTransform(100f, 100f);
g.ScaleTransform(40f, 40f);
g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Olive, points);
g.Transform=mx;

g.TranslateTransform(300f, 100f);
g.ScaleTransform(80f, 80f);
g.FillPolygon(Brushes.MediumOrchid, points);
g.Restore(st);
```

which draws to polygons of the same shape on different locations with different sizes.

[image: Form]

(red annotations added by me)

Comment: do 100,100 in TranslateTransform is center of polygon?

Comment: You know your polygon is a triangle and center needs to be calculated first if you want to draw around it.

Comment: I have added an example printout in winforms for an example.

Comment: Note that `var state  = g.Save();` and `g.Restore(state);` can be used to revert the scale transformation back to default.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. A simple, rather silly solution would be to use linq:

```
double resizeValue = 1.5;
points.Select(x => new Point(x.X*resizeValue, x.Y*resizeValue);
```

That way is simple to understand, I think. May be better ways, but if this is all you're doing, it's probably sufficient.

Comment: Next question will be how to resize from center of polygon, and not from [0,0] :)

Comment: I want use center of polygon for resize.

Comment: Just wanted to note that it'll only work if you don't need the polygons to share the same center. Otherwise you'll need to perform a simple translation, additionally.

Comment: You can at least add or subtract a value as well. `x.X*resizeValue+translation`, where translation can be any int. Just do it for Y as well. If this was OpenGL, you'd just multiply it by some matrix that had the correct properties, but this isn't that.